# How to display Elements in Wpf ListBox in a row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I got a bit of xaml:

```
                    <ListBox Grid.Column="1"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Channels}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Item}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">                                       
                                </WrapPanel>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    </ListBox>
```

Right now the listbox will display a checkbox for every element together with a string. All those items will be displayed in one row and the listbox will be scrollable when there are too many items.

I would like the listbox to display the items more like a WinForms `CheckedListBox` does automatically. It should determine automatically how many columns fit into it and display the Checkboxes accordingly. Is this possible and if yes, can you tell me how to do it?

thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you know how many items it will need to display pr. row, or is it dynamic?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the WinForms CheckedListBox display differs? I [looked it up](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/checkedcombobox/CheckedComboBox.PNG) and it seems very much like what you'd get with your XAML above.

Comment: The CheckedListBox automatically orders the items in as many columns as there is place for in the checkedlistbox. If i resize the control the checkedlistbox is in (so that the checkedlistbox gets resizes also) the amount of columns gets adjusted.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't require a `ListBox` you can use an `ItemsControl` instead:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Channels}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Item}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        </WrapPanel>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Flat Eric where did you get the idea that the question author didn't  want to use a `ListBox`? It's worth pointing out to them that if they *do* want to use a `ListBox` (and it does appear that they do), then they can also do this using the `ListBox.ItemsPanel` property.

Comment: @Sheridan: I tested with a ListBox but it did not wrap at the bottom of the screen

Comment: Then this doesn't really answer the question author's question, does it? However, there really shouldn't be any difference between using a `ListBox` and an `ItemsControl`, except for the obvious.

Comment: @Sheridan: Since the author didn't bind the selected item it seems to me that he does not need this feature.

Comment: @user3596113: Have you tested my solution? Can you tell me what differs from your expected behavior?

Comment: @Sheridan: I know, just wanted to know from the author if he has tested it.